# How to reduce memory in multiprocessing operation

Tags: python, memory, multiprocessing

I am performing a string manipulation task multiple times. My function takes in a string of approximately 3GB and does some operations on it and writes to a file. I wanted to do this multiple times in parallel using Pool, but I am running into some unexpected issues on my machine. I have 32 CPUs and 128GB of RAM which seemed sufficient. However, it seems without pattern that the memory can sometimes be overwhelmed. Is there a way to reduce the overhead memory (like would deleting the string after the function reduce the memory python is using). I am not sure how Pool is managing the memory since I am not familiar with multiprocessing. Here is the basic code framework:

```
pool = Pool(32)
the_string = 'ababba' #this is in actuality a very long string
def doSomethingToString(a_string): 
    #load string and do stuff 
    return 1
input_list = [the_string]*32
pool.map(doSomethingToString, input_list)
```

Comment: So you are trying to run up to 32 workers each of them will attempt to do something with a 3Gb string. Even if there's no additional overhead from calculations then this requires 96Gb or RAM to store data for all the workers. More likely it should be getting very close to your max memory. For starters, you can reduce the number of workers.

Comment: Yes, that was my quick fix. I was wondering if there was a way in multithreading to remove or "queue" the worker if it reaches near max memory.

Comment: Ideally, instead of working on a Python string you'd work on a SHM buffer, if the algorithm is such that there can be only one copy that all instances work against.

Comment: That said, Python is not generally a good choice of languages if you need tight control over memory allocation. I'd probably reach for Rust instead.